# PHP making an URL link work inserting the $variables the right syntax way

Tags: php, url

I have this link that works.

```
echo '<a href="?country=Estonia&from_language=Russian&into_language=Latvian&submitted=true&
page='.$x. '">'.$x.'</a> ';
```

But I need the nouns Estonia, Russian and Latvian replaced by scalar variables like $country, $from_language, $into_language.

I have tried all possible combinations of dots and single and double quotes. I always get syntax errors. I don't know how the embed the variables there.

Anybody knows?

thank you

Comment: You know how to concatenate the `$x`, but not other variables?

Comment: read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I see _everybody_ just crams variables in the string. Guys, **quote your HTML and URLs**

Comment: lanzz, maybe you know what's behind the variables. I don't and for all I know the variables may be hardcoded correctly. But when using `printf` it's trivial to add such escaping if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use something easy one like `sprintf` or `printf`.

eg:

```
printf('<a href="?country=%s&from_language=%s&into_language=%s&submitted=true&
page=%s">%s</a>', $country, $fromLanguage, $toLanguage, $pageID, $dispText);
```

You could also use something like encoding with double quote sign like:

```
echo "<a href=\"?country={$country}&from_language={$fromLanguage}&into_language={$toLanguage}&submitted=true&
    page={$pageID}\">{$dispText}</a>"
```

Comment: why vote down? this answer is probably the least fiddly. this could also help with input sanitation if it were required.

Comment: And what happens when one of these has a & in it (I'm not the downvote though)?

Comment: Which you've neglected to mention.

Comment: @corbin true, but that's not what the question asked for. might be worth a mention though.

Comment: I did all the input sanitation with all the filter var functions. Finally the link that worked is this one:   echo "<a href='?country={$country}&from_language={$from_language}&into_language={$into_language}&submitted=true&page=$x'>$x</a>";

Answer (score 8):

Do yourself a massive favour and use [`http_build_query`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/http_build_query):

```
<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query(array(
    'country' => $country,
    'fromLanguage' => $fromLanguage,
    'somethingElse' => $somethingElse,
    '...' => '...'
), '', '&amp;'); ?>">Link</a>
```

Comment: i didn't know about `http_build_query` . very useful, thanks :)

Comment: @jammypeach I would guess that about 90% of PHP developers don't know about it :).  Glad I could help.

Comment: For what `htmlspecialchars`? Just throwing functions on things because you think the more you throw the safer it is?

Comment: hakre, http_build_query will actually output invalid HTML code.

Comment: @hakre Aw damn. I forgot to mysql_real_escape_string it.  urlencoded does not mean HTML safe.

Comment: @EmilVikström: Proof it. I'd say it's a matter of using the function in a right way. There is not need to run `htmlspecialchars` here.

Comment: @hakre It takes a very borderline case to provoke an issue. The crux is that URL encoding uses & whereas HTML needs &amp;.  Am on my phone now, but if Emil does not provide an example, I will later.  (Edit: with known array keys, the htmlspecialchars is likely useless. Have not played around with trying to break it via array values.)

Comment: If `&amp;` is the only point what you're concerned about, see the edit.

Comment: It's of course the ampersand I'm talking about. I know you can run it like `http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;')` but that is rather clunky in my opinion. I like separation of concerns.

Comment: Making &amp; the separator should make it safe.  I prefer the letting http_build_query URL encode it and htmlspecialchars HTML 'encode' it though.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid to put variables directly into string when not extremely simple. Use concatenation instead, and escape string if you want to make something good:

```
echo '<a href="?country=' . htmlentities($country) . 
     '&from_language=' . htmlentities($from_language) . 
     '&into_language=' . htmlentities($into_language) . 
     '&submitted=true&page=' . intval($x) . '">' . htmlentities($x) . '</a> ';
```

Anyway, if you really want it the complex way, you have to consider that you need doble quotes for HTML attributes, but double quotes are needed to wrap the PHP string because you want to put variables in it. So, you must escape HTML double quotes. Try:

```
echo "<a href=\"?country={$country}&from_language={$from_language}&into_language={$into_language}&submitted=true&page=" . $x . '">' . $x . '</a> ';
```

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, that also eases things a lot for the future. I never liked having to write complex strings and breaking it into parts makes it much easier!

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers of Corbin and KoolKabin gives you this easy-to-read snippet:

```
printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',
       htmlspecialchars(
           http_build_query(array(
                                  'country' => $country,
                                  'from_language' => $from_language,
                                  'into_language' => $into_language,
                                  'submitted' => 'true',
                                  'page' => $x
                                  ))
                        ),
       htmlspecialchars($x));
```

**Parametrization**

[printf](http://php.net/printf) and [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) are very useful for adding parameters to strings. They make it easy to add escaping or complex values without making the string itself unreadable. You can always see at a glance what string it is by the first parameter.

[http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) is also a way of parametrizing, but for the querystring. The main use is that you don't need to focus on the syntax of querystrings at all.

**Escaping**

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) makes sure that the data is fit for insertion into HTML code. It's similar to escaping in SQL queries to avoid SQL injections, only here we want to avoid HTML injections (also called XSS or [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

http_build_query will automatically make sure that all values are escaped for insertion *as an URL* in the address field in a browser. This *does not* guarantee fitness for insertion into *HTML code*. htmlspecialchars is therefore needed for the querystring as well!

Comment: @Emil: With less words and more precise: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10913016/367456

Answer (score 1):

If you scripts output HTML, consider to configure the output setting for argument separators [`arg_separator.output`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.output):

```
ini_set('arg_separator.output', '&amp;');
```

You can then simply create the URI query info path by using `http_build_query`:

```
$country = 'de';
$fromLanguage = 'en_EN';

?>

<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query(compact('country', 'fromLanguage')); ?>">Link</a>
```

Which will give you a perfectly validly encoded output, which is immune to injections:

```
<a href="?country=de&amp;fromLanguage=en_EN">Link</a>
```

[Full Demo](http://codepad.org/WOI1uqcJ)

Comment: Yes, it does output the parameters. It needs however the name of the page, otherwise it would just give out something like : http://localhost/country=Estonia&from_language=Russian&into_language=Latvian&submitted=true&page=2

Comment: Not when you make properly use of realtive URIs, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.1

Comment: No, let me take a look if there is some less-technical description of what a relative URI is http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#h-2.1.3 , is that better?

Comment: Well, I had read about absolute and relative paths and in principle the adjectives are somewhat descriptive of what they mean, yet, how to implement that in the http_build_query maybe is not that evident.

Comment: You don't need to. Place a `?` before it, and you create a URI relative to the page it is the link in. It's more a concept than a specific function you need to call or parameter to set.

Comment: In the example about the arg_separator, the link does have the parameters but does not show the pages page=1, page=2. I truly appreciate what I know it is really great teaching. So one example had the page=1 etc but did not have the main page. translator.php and the second example has the base page, translator.php but does not have the pages =1, page = 2 etc. I know these are knowledgeable advices but at the time of learning if I had to struggle in new concepts ...

Comment: Yes, add the other variables you need to have. Look at the code, you can change it.

Comment: Hi, well yes, I have managed to get it working as you wrote. Yet, of course, I only get Link Link Link which, yes, if you click on them they do give out correct results and change pages but, it is all the same word. I tried to introduce a variable counter such as $counter += $counter; and put it as the page link but then, the url breaks and nowthing is shown. Of course I opened php tags but still. I like your proposal because it is clean, few words and safe, yet, I am not succeding at putting a page link that shows consecutive numbers instead of the same word, despite that it does bring ok

Answer (score -1):

```
$country = 'Estonia';
$from_language = 'Russian';
$into_language = 'Latvian';
echo '<a href="?country='.$country.'from_language='.$from_language.'&into_language='.$into_language.'&submitted=true&page='.$x. '">'.$x.'</a> ';
```

OR

```
echo "<a href=\"?country=$country&from_language=$from_language&into_language=$into_language&submitted=true&page=$x\">$x</a>";
```

OR

```
echo "<a href=\"?country={$country}&from_language={$from_language}&into_language={$into_language}&submitted=true&page={$x}\">{$x}</a>";
```